# C - control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]

Tags: c

I have this, and when I try to compile, the terminal give me the error; someone can help me?

```
int e=0;

float func(float x, float y, float z)
{
     e++;
     if((x*x)+(y*y)+(z*z)<=4)
     return 2.0;
}
```

Comment: What should `func` return if `(x*x)+(y*y)+(z*z)<=4` isn't true?

Comment: Please always use braces. Saves embarrassment preventing your trousers falling down.

Comment: Also, use spaces and remove unnecessary brackets. Those hurt people's eyes. What's better with a few bytes saved? Isn't `if (x*x + y*y + z*z <=4)` easier to read?

Answer (score 3):

What should `func` return if `(x*x)+(y*y)+(z*z)<=4` isn't true? You haven't defined that case, but there's nothing afterward in the function.  The flow of control (i.e., the execution path) has reached the end of the function without returning anything, but something *should* be returned, because the function is non-void.  Hence, "control reaches end of non-void function".

Answer (score 2):

Your function is not always returning values, because it only return value (2.0) only if `if ()` test is true. Using indentation will help.

Answer (score 1):

That is because the `return` statement follows the `if()` block.

If the statement is true, the function will return `2.0`, and if it's false it will reach the end of the function without returning a value.

Answer (score 1):

Your code

```
int e=0;

float func(float x, float y, float z)
{
     e++;
     if((x*x)+(y*y)+(z*z)<=4)
     return 2.0;
}
```

If you used indentation would be

```
int e=0;

float func(float x, float y, float z)
{
     e++;
     if ((x*x)+(y*y)+(z*z)<=4)
         return 2.0;
}
```

If you used braces would be

```
int e=0;

float func(float x, float y, float z)
{
     e++;
     if((x*x)+(y*y)+(z*z)<=4)
     {
        return 2.0;
     }
}
```

This would be self evident that paths do not return a value.

But also the statement

```
if((x*x)+(y*y)+(z*z)<=4)
```

Could do with tidying up to make it more readable

Perhaps

```
if (((x*x) + (y*y) + (z*z)) <= 4)
```